# Boolean operation between a form and a spiral

Tags: modifiers

I'm designing a real object: a cylinder box dispender.
It will be 3D printed: two mirror versions of the same object (named Half.shell) will be printed and then screwed or glued together.
Just before gluing/assembling these two parts, I want to insert a thin band of metal between them, and give it a spiral form, so a spiral groove must be made available in the Half.shell object.
Context is Blender 2.9.1 with extra curve add on.
The problem I have is when I want to make the spiral groove into Half.shell object.
I've built a spiral of cubes, starting with a cube, add modifier array of 780 objects, then add modifier curve following an archemedian spiral curve created with the extra curve addon.
I've tried boolean modifier as well as BTool addon to make the difference/groove, with no success: the resulting shape is a real mess with triangles going everywhere and nothing becomes editable from this point.

[image]

Edit1:
-the Spiral.of.cubes object sometimes grows by itself, as if I've scaled it on the X & Y axis, and reopening blender can help, but not always. This problem occurs when I'm changing selection in object mode and edit mode.
-so may be the way I'm doing the spiral.of.cube is not the good way.
-Spiral.of.cube is in fact a spiral of parallelepiped 1.5x1.5x2mm

Comment: Hello, so what are all these cylinder for? I guess your problem is just between the spiral and the shell? Just to make sure...

Comment: Yes, you can hide or delete them. They will be real world objects (jars or something like that), so I've drawn them to check they fit into the inside of the spiral.

Comment: there are several problems like for your spiral inner faces and overlapping vertices, that's easily fixable before applying the modifiers if you delete 2 faces of the cube and click on the array merge option, but your shell has also bad topology like inner faces, overlapping faces, flipped normals, you need to fix that and the boolean will work much better

Comment: also you should probably simplify the topology of the flat surface of the shell (where the boolean will happen), it will probably help

Comment: Thank you. When saying boolean modifier you mean regular/default blender boolean modifier or BTool add on ?

Comment: I wil search on the forum how to do all these operations to obtain a better topology for my shell.

Comment: Regular Boolean modifier, I'm going to make an answer except I can't go fully in detail for your shell object as there are several problems that you need to fix and that are hard to explain in few words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do :

- Select your spiral cube object, delete 2 faces so that it won't generate inner faces, apply both the *Array* and *Curve* modifier, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*:

[image]

- Fill each tip with <kbd>F</kbd> :

[image]

- The topology of you shell is messy, go in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> *> Merge By Distance*, in the *Operator* box choose a *Merge Distance* of 0,001 :

[image]

- But you also need to delete inner faces, overlapping faces, and you need to recalculate the normals (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>), especially if you plan to print in 3D.
- Once everything done, you can merge all the faces of your shell surface, where the boolean is supposed to happen:

[image]

- The *Boolean* will work fine:

[image]

Comment: Your help is really appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some additionnal questions: To Compute normals: Edit Mode->Select all->Alt N->Recalculate outside ?

Comment: Yes, also, check the normals: open the Viewport Overlays panel and enable Face Orientation

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me days. Hard for me to check this toggle since all menus are transparent (graphic card is an old ATI from 2012, seems to be no more supported in new versions of blender...) and this region is full of static information underneath,

Comment: So maybe use a previous version of Blender, Boolean has been improved in 2.91 but it should work with 2.79

Comment: When "Face orientation" is checked, faces become blue or pink instead of grey, is that a normal behavior or is it my outdated graphic card ?

Comment: it should be either blue (normal orientation) or red (invert of the normal), but it may be altered by a setting (?)

Comment: Blender 2.79b was not able to reopen my blender 2.9.1 .blend file (crash).
So I've exported to .obj in 2.9.1 and opened the .obj with 2.79b without any problem :I've just loose the collection hierarchy but it's a minor problem.
The rendering with this ATI fire pro is way much better with 2.79b than with 2.9.1

Comment: If you can't work with 2.8 or 2.9, and can't open the file in 2.79, you can append all the obects: File > Append > double-click on the file, go in the Object folder and select all

Comment: That's a great tip. Thanks.